# Wicket: getApplication Differences

Tags: wicket

I have a question about wicket getApplication.

1. What is the difference between getApplication() and getSession().getApplication?
2. When you deploy the wicket application, is the wicketapplication object shared between all users who run it? Or is a separate instance created every time a user hits the page?

Answer (score 9):

1. In case of Component.getApplication() the Application object is fetched and returned via a threadlocal by calling Application.get(). On the other hand getSession().getApplication() first retrieves the session object, and then delegates to the same Application.get() static call, which can be more expensive due to the session lookup, so calling getSession() is not optimal. You can pretty much use Application.get() instead of both options.
2. The Application object is a singleton, it isn't even serializable and it is shared between each thread inside the same jvm running the application.

Comment: I guess the methods exist so you have a convenient way to get the Application instance from whatever class you are (pages, components, or session). Having this method always available also disencourages programmers to hold the application instance in a variable (thus increasing the risk of unintendedly keeping a reference to it for serialization (using a final variable inside an anonymous inner class, for example). If you always use this method (or Application.get()), you are safe, because in the worst case, you keep a reference to a serializable object (component or page), which is allowed.